# How to carry variables from imported functions to the main file (Python 3.8.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm making a small game and wanted a settings page function that's in a seperate .py file to keep things more clean and easily editable. I have a global variable called textSpeed (which I use the global keyword to use properly in the function) which I change in this runSettings function, but when I print the variable back in my main file it hasn't changed.

The code in the main file (main.py)

```
from settings import runSettings
textSpeed = "not set"
runSettings()
print(textSpeed)
```

The code from the settings fuction file (settings.py)

```
def runSettings():
    global textSpeed
    textSpeed = input("select text speed. ")
    print(textSpeed)
    return textSpeed
```

Comment: when you are modifying a global var in your `runSettings()` function you are modifying a variable global to that file(i.e. settings.py), to print the var that was changed by your `runSettings()` try printing `settings.textSpeed`.

Comment: if you don't want `textSpeed` var to be owned by the settings file, you can import everything from that file without a namespace `from settings import *`

Comment: Do you actually have a variable called `textSpeed` inside `settings.py`? Or when you put the `global` you mean for it to be the one from `main.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `runSettings` function already retuns the value it sets as well. Instead of messing with mixing namespaces and importing global variables, just use the returned value in `main.py`:

```
textSpeed = runSettings()
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid circular import, I advise you to create a third file if you wish to keep it this way. Let's call it `varSpeed.py` with the following code:

```
global textSpeed
textSpeed = "not set"
```

Then you can `import varSpeed` from both other files have access to that variable without the circular issue.

Comment: That would cause a big mess as both files have `textSpeed` variables in them

Comment: wait not sure. It is not clear from OP if there is actually a variable in `settings.py` called like that or if he meant for the one from `main.py` to be the global

Comment: Actually it's correct this way. global textSpeed will reach to the global var in main.py

Comment: This gives the following error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'runSettings' from partially initialized module 'settings' (most likely due to a circular import)" as I have to import the settings module to my main.py in order to use the function so can't import main.py

Answer (score 1):

textSpeed is a local variable - local to the main module.

You need to reference the variable from settings.

```
import settings 
settings.textSpeed = "not set"
runSettings()
print(settings.textSpeed)
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are trying to change a variable from a different file, while you have not imported the file. I think the easiest way to handle this is to use a class variable like this:

Main file:

```
from class_file import MyClass

MyClass.run_settings()
print(MyClass.text_speed)
```

Settings file:

```
class MyClass:

    text_speed = 'n/a'

    @staticmethod
    def run_settings():
        MyClass.text_speed = input("Select text speed: ")
        return MyClass.text_speed
```